# Вывод содержимого папки средствами PHP

Tags: php, html, файлы

Добрый день, товарищи.

Нужно вывести содержимое папки средствами PHP, пример идеи:

Есть папка **path/img**.

Нужно, чтобы все файлы в папке выводились так:

```
<a href="/path/img/file1.jpg"><img src="/path/img/file1.jpg"/></a>
<a href="/path/img/file2.jpg"><img src="/path/img/file2.jpg"/></a>
```

Сам делаю так:

```
<?
$current_dir = '/home/site/public_html/pages/gallery/img/';
$dir = opendir($current_dir);
while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
    echo "<img src=\"/path/img/$file\" width=\"250px\"/>";
}
closedir($dir);
?>
```

Результат моего кода:

```
<img src="/path/img/." width="250px">
<img src="/path/img/IMG_6155.JPG" width="250px">
<img src="/path/img/.." width="250px">
```

Мой вариант с ошибками - откуда-то добавились лишние строки кода с ".".

Помогите, пожалуйста, с данной задачей.

Благодарю за внимание!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте итератор:

```
$dir = '...'; // где ищем

foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot() || $fileInfo->isDir()) continue;

    printf(
        '<img src="/path/img/%s" width="250px" />%s', 
        $fileInfo->getFilename(),
        PHP_EOL
    );
}
```

Лишние `.` и `..` — это сокращения *(поправьте знатоки unix'а)* для текущей директории и родительской, соответственно. В моём примере за их исключение отвечает `DirectoryIterator::isDot()`

Либо проверяйте, чтобы имя не было равно `.` и `..` — других нет.

Comment: > поправьте знатоки unix'а

Не могу ничего сказать про истоки, но такая нотация сейчас работает вообще везде.

Comment: Меня смущает слово "сокращения" - не нашёл, как называются эти... сущности.

Answer (score 2):

Можно также старым добрым методом:

```
$path = '/path/img/';

if ($open = scandir($path)) {
    foreach ($open as $k => $v) {
        if ($v != "." && $v != "..") {
            echo '<img src="'.$path.$v.'" width="250px">';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: DirecoryIterator предоставляет несравненно большую гибкость и удобство в использовании. И лучше всего при таком подходить тримать слэши в конце $path и начале $v и ставить слэш между ними.

Answer (score 0):

Пример

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('common');
/** @var $file DirectoryIterator */
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    if($file->isFile()){ 
      printf("%s\n", $file); 
    } 
}
```

+
[Статья](http://simpledev.su/2016/04/12/directoryiterator-instrument-dlya-raboty-s-fa/) где болле детально описанно как это сделать